# Pass server data into root App class of Aurelia app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aurelia

When using Aurelia, what is the best way to get dynamic server data into the root view model class without having to make a second trip to the server? Below is a very super simple example:

**body of the root view**

```
<body aurelia-app>
  <script src="/path/to/system.js"></script>
  <script src="/path/to/config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
  </script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App {
  name;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
  ${name}
</template>
```

If `name` is a value that is coming from the server, how can we get that value into the root `App` class without having to make a second trip to the server? Is there any syntax/capability in Aurelia that allows you to pass dynamic data like this into the constructor of the root class via HTML attributes? Maybe something like this (ASP.NET MVC syntax used below)?

```
<body aurelia-app params="name: '@Model.Name'">
```

And then this can be received via the constructor like this:

```
export class App {
  name;
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

I've seen the `@bindable` decorator, but I don't think it works on the root view, or does it (examples)?

Comment: I found one possibility [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781268/how-to-pass-debug-vs-release-args-to-an-aurelia-app-within-asp-net-mvc). In this answer they are registering a module through a `System.set` call that executes when the view is rendered (with data from Razor) and then importing that module into the view model class. I guess if there aren't any alternatives then this might be the best solution.